# How do I use pandas dataframes to select the first column as array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to collect the values of the first column of a pandas dataframe into an array. How can I accomplish this?

So far I have tried this:

```
first_column_values = df.iloc[:,[0]]
```

But it is not the result I wish to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. It should be:

`first_column_values = df.iloc[:, 0].values`

Comment: Thanks! and on an unrelated note, you have a cool title, "water resources engineer".